# Html Link not working inconjunction with jquery effects

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

I am trying to integrate jquery effect in conjunction with html link for instance :
when i click on a link it should display the particular div which is in the master page , It should also navigate to the required page , below is the code which I am using to achieve this with no success:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

 $('#services-sub-menu').hide();
   $('#services').click(function () {
     $('#services-sub-menu').show("slow");
     return false;
      });

});
 <div class="Menu2"><a href="/articles" id="articles">ARTICLES</a><br /> <a href="/services" id="services">TESTIMONIALS</a><br /><a href="#" id="contact">CONTACT US</a></div>
 </div><div class="sub-menu">
  <div id="services-sub-menu"><a href="/services-submenu" /></div>

</div>
```

The jquery effect is working but the page is not navigating to the services page

Comment: What's up with `</umbraco:Macro>`? I don't see an opening tag anywhere, which could very well be your problem.

Comment: i have removed it , sorry for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By returning false at the end of your click, you basically tell the browser to halt it's default behaviour.

The jQuery equivelent of this would be:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

where

```
$('#services').click(function (event) {
```

Removing your `return false` will allow the link to work as expected however it may redirect before your anmiation has completed.

What you can do is add a callback to the show method and redirect using Javascript inside there.

```
$('#services-sub-menu').show("slow",function(){
  // Stuff that will happen when animation has completed
  window.location.replace(redirectionUrl);
});
```

**Update**

Here's a very basic working example: http://jsfiddle.net/XakkU/

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="clicker">Click me </a>
<div id="showMe">Hold on, we're taking off!</div>

$('#clicker').click(function(event){
    $('#showMe').show('slow',function(){
        window.location.replace($('#clicker').attr('href'));
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: can you provide a simplest example please

Comment: well what if i want the showme div to remain on the page even after animation as it is on the master page

Comment: If you're redirecting to another page and you want to keep the message in place you need to either pass a flag to the new page so it knows to show the message, or only update the part of the page you want to change (using ajax probably). That's a different question though.

Comment: Why are you redirecting the user to a new page?

Comment: Basically What i am trying to acheive is , when a user click on the services , the system should navigate to service page, also displaying submenu for services which is under a div

Comment: If you're just wanting to show the submenu, what's the redirect for?

Comment: Root page is Service (which has some information) subpages are Service 1 , service 2 ..... which are wrapped up in the div and should be visible when the root page service is clicked

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3531/discussion-between-mr-a-and-jamie-dixon)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the line

```
return false;
```

from your javascript. It prevents further processing of the click, and therefore link does not work.

Comment: i need to return false to prevent some css over riding

Comment: Then your best bet is using the callback function along with the effect, as Jamie advised.